# Reverse Geocoding in Here / Nokia Map

Tags: javascript, dictionary, here-api

I am trying to implement the new structure of here map(asp.net web app) , however, I cannot see the features of passing the location information and retrieving the certain address via javascript and stick that info with a bubble on the marker.

Appreciate for any advises.
cheers

Comment: I'm sorry, it's entirely unclear what you're asking. What have you tried, and what problem are you having?

Comment: It was about the attribute of locations - It's done. However, my current problem is that how to call the reverseGeoCode method more than once to have more marker on the map with the address on bubbles?      I cannot do loop that :      
map.addListener("displayready", function () {
            searchManager.reverseGeoCode({
                latitude: reverseGeoCodeTerm.latitude,
                longitude: reverseGeoCodeTerm.longitude,
                onComplete: processResults                
            });            
        });    as I've got more lat and long

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking to make multiple concurrent reverse geocode requests. There is no problem in doing this, since the calls are asynchronous, you just need to keep a count on which requests have completed, and call your "do-after-all-completed" stuff once at the end:

e.g:

```
function concurrentSearch(map){
    // we will put our address markers into this container
    addressContainer = new nokia.maps.map.Container();
    managersFinished = 0;

    //Locations to be displayed
    latLngs= [[10,30], [-117.5, 15.3] ... etc];
    var  i = latLngs.length;

    while(i--) {
        nokia.places.search.manager.reverseGeocode({
            latitude: latLngs[i][0],
            longitude: latLngs[i][1],
            onComplete: processResults
        });
    }
}
```

With a callback function as shown:

```
   function processResults(data, requestStatus) {
        if (requestStatus == "OK") {
            // if we are finished, we add a marker for the mapped position
            var marker = new nokia.maps.map.StandardMarker(data.location[0].position);
            marker.content = data.location[0].address.text; // add your content here
            addressContainer.objects.add(
                marker);
            //increment the counter to notify another manager has finished
            managersFinished++;
        } else if(requestStatus === "ERROR") {
            // we'll also increment in case of an error
            managersFinished++;
        }

        // if all managers are finished, we call the final function
        if(managersFinished === latLngs.length) {
            onAllManagersFinished();
        }
    }
```

And the final clean up:

```
 function onAllManagersFinished() {
        //we get the bounding box of the container
        var bbox = addressContainer.getBoundingBox();

        // if the bounding box is null then there are no objects inside
        // meaning no markers have been added to it

        if (bbox != null) {
                // we have at least one address mapped
                // so we add the container and zoomTo it
                map.objects.add(addressContainer);
                map.zoomTo(bbox);
        } else {
                // otherwise we'll pop up an error message
                alert("There are no addresses to show :(");
        }
    }
```

Futhermore, you could add a single event handler on the **container**, which could open the infobubbles for all of your locations:

```
addressContainer.addListener(
    "click", 
    function (evt) { 
        infoBubbles.openBubble(evt.target.content, // content is your own stuff...
        evt.target.coordinate);
    }
);
```

If you need to pass in more of your information when reverse-geocoding, you can do it in the manner described in the question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18190043/is-there-a-way-to-associate-the-reponse-and-query-while-invoking-nokia-reverse-g)

The solution to a similar problem (multiple geocoding requests) can be found [here](http://rawgithub.com/heremaps/examples/master/maps_api_for_javascript/demos/concurrent-search-requests/index.html).